# Removing special characters in Json while sending to server

Tags: android, json

hi after computing im getting json as below

```
{"xxxx":"{\"value\":\"http:\\\/\\\/blaze.mobiclay.net\\\/action\\\/qzproject\\\/feed\\\/20111015\\\/getfeedurl?feedID=702\",\"type\":\"RSS\"}","yyyy":"{\"value\":\"chg\",\"type\":\"String\"}","zzzz (mins)":"{\"value\":\"3\",\"type\":\"String\"}",
```

but i need it as below when i need to send it to server

```
{"xxxx":{"type":"RSS","value":""},"zzzz (mins)":{"type":"String","value":""},"yyyy":{"type":"String","value":""}}
```

Comment: post the code where you create the object

Comment: well its a long process where i get the json and make changes to it and then create new json and convert it to string ...i have edited my  question

Comment: you probably have a new JSONObject().add(new JSONObject().toString()) somehow

Answer (score 1):

I think this is you are looking for:-)
[encode](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/EncodingExamples)

and [decode](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/wiki/DecodingExamples)